# Why are the Build generated XCRRequiresAttribNotFound values not the same?

Tags: xamarin, msbuild

In the **WinPhone** project of a **VS 2015 v2** cross platform solution with **Xamarin.Forms v2.2.0.13**, two versions of **ExceptionStringTable.resx** are generated in the **'System Xaml/en-US'** and the **'WindowsBase/en-US'** folders with different contents. At the moment a dependent assembly, **XCRRequiresAttribNotFound**, found in both files, has conflicting values during build, one having an extra 'a' in the string. Since they are Build generated, why are they not the same value?

[Comparison of Values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aQgqq.png)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have Platform specific assemblies referenced in your PCL. In this case, it seems that you have a reference to `WindowsBase.dll` somehow within your PCL. (This could be inside something like `PresentationCore.dll` or similar).

I would recommend that you do the following:

1. Compare this against a File -> New Forms Project (PCL) - To see what default references are within Forms by default in the PCL.
2. Replace any old desktop/platform specific code with the Forms APIs instead - https://developer.xamarin.com/api/root/Xamarin.Forms/
3. Profit!

If you have any further problems, I would recommend using `grep` on certain strings like `WindowsBase` to see exactly where this is coming from. In this case it's a reference to `PresentationCore.dll`

Comment: Thanks for your recommendations. I did remove the Windows.*.dll references, but that didn’t solve the problem. Looking at the detailed build output I noticed a complaint that WinPhone was including a ToolsVersion 12 into it; it was itself ToolsVersion 14 . The issue was that the root (portable) and WinPhone projects were referencing two different ToolsVersion, 12 and 14 respectfully, and WinPhone was referencing the root. I changed the root and the problems reported went away.

Comment: In my case, this worked like a charm.  I was referencing Windows and PresentationCore for the MessageBoxResult enum.  I removed those references and refactored a little and BAM!!!  Thank you so much!